# Android Webview page load message

Tags: java, android, webview

Im trying to add a message on the webview if the page thats trying to load to fails.  Is this possible? If so, is it possible for the message to replace the default "the webpage failed to load" screen?

activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.technotalkative.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to override onReceivedError() method of your webViewClient?